# c++ palindrome program using array

Tags: c++, arrays, palindrome

I am having a problem with my palindrome program. I am required to use arrays and show how a push and pop would work without .push or .pop. The trouble I am having is when I enter a 3 letter word it will say yes it is a palindrome but if I enter a word that is 4 or more characters it will say not a palindrome even if it is. ex. kayak. Dont see where I am going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char original[13];
    int stkptr=-1;
    int x = strlen(original)-1;


    cout <<"Enter a character"<<endl;

    for( ++stkptr ; stkptr<13;stkptr++)
    //store user input into the array
    {

        cin>>original[stkptr];

        if(original[stkptr]=='0')
            break;

        cout<<original[stkptr]<<"  Stack pointer is: "<<stkptr<<endl;



    }
    //POP
    for (--stkptr; stkptr>=0;stkptr--)
        cout<<original[stkptr]<<" Stack pointer is: "<<stkptr<<endl;



    for(int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (original[i] == original[x-i])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nNot a palidrome\n"<<endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nIndeed Palidrome\n"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: One thing: you set x before you get input.

Comment: You do a strlen(original), but original is not initialized.  Is this also part of the original code?

Comment: Are you restricted not to use standard library algorithms? You are including `<string>`, so it is not clear. But it is a one-liner with the standard library.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for here, but I have a solution posted that does not use push or pop. Not sure why'd you need to use them either.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool checkIsPalindrome(string s){
    int nLength = s.length();
    string s1, s2;
    if(nLength & 1) // is Odd
        nLength--;

    nLength = nLength/2;

    //take the first half
    s1 = s.substr(0,nLength);

    //pop off the last half of characters into the string
    for(int i = s.length()-1; i > nLength; i--)
       s2+= s.at(i);

    if(s1 == s2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: Yes, StackOverflow does not make that easy.

Comment: it's very easy, you just need to know how to use the editor. Paste in your code, then highlight all of it and hit the button that looks like `{}`, if you pasted it in with indentation, it will be preserved

Comment: stackoverflow could be consuming the tab event when you're in the text box though, it's quite the annoyance when I realize I can't tab sections of code.

Comment: write the code in an actual text editor first, then paste into SO. That's what I do

Answer (score 0):

Though you overly complicated the logic, I will tell what is wrong the current code.

you are going wrong with `x`. You initialize it to string length when there is no "string" (Also, your char array should have a `\0` at the end for strlen() to work). Assign `stkptr-1` to `x` before `pop` and remove `pop`.

And in your loop you should iterate only till half of the array, since you are comparing char-by-char from begin and end

```
for(int i = 0; i <= x/2; i++)
```